# How to only select the lookahead matches

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, actionscript

i have found a pretty good regEx but I have difficulty excluding part of the match.

What I want is select parentheses, but ONLY if there's 1 number (multiple digits) between the start and end parentheses or a single character or if its empty between them (). If theres some character in front of the () it should not select it. I'm using it to replace some part of a string therefore I want to only match the parentheses since I want to remove them. The current regExp matches the parentheses and the part inside them.

```
.(?<=[^a-z]\()([\d]*|[a-zA-Z])(?=\)).

(x+2)/(x)   -> only select ( ) in (x) 
-(2)+.      -> only select ( ) in (2)
(wsd).      -> select nothing
(x)^2+2     -> only select ( ) in (x)
sin(x).     -> select nothing
(22313)a.   -> only select ( ) in (22313)
+23-3()/(3x)+(x).  -> only select () in () and ( ) in (x)
sin(x)+3*x^2+(x)+23 -> only select ( ) in (x)
```

Any idea how to NOT-select the part between the parentheses?

I have set up a regexp tester:
https://regex101.com/r/fYDm2L/1

Comment: Please add a tag of the language or tool you use to your question. The [regex] tag alone is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to match parenthesis one at a time, describe the whole substring and use capture groups you can refer to in the replacement string:

```
var result:String = str.replace(/ (^|[^a-z]) \( (\d*|[a-z]) \) /gix, "$1$2");
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wp2Esr/1)

Comment: Wow didn't know that one could do that - works beautifully. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Python solution would be:

x - input line

```py
import re

for el in re.finditer(r"[YOUR REGEX HERE]", x):
     print(x[el.start():el.end()])
     x=x.replace(x[el.start():el.end()], x[el.start():el.end()].replace("(", "").replace(")", ""))
```

So - from your question I assumed your regex works fine (please do correct me, if I'm wrong) and you only want to replace parenthesis, if regex is matched.

In such case - finditer will iterate through all the matched strings, then by referencing every found phrase by: `x[el.start():el.end()]` - you can replace it by it's fixed (without parenthesis) form.

Comment: Yeah regExp is fine, I'm writing in actionsctipt and wanted to write: string.replace(regexp,"") and remove the parthenses .... i wanted to avoid a loop that goes through the results